# If $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., $\int |f| < \infty$, and if $\int |f_n| \to A$, is $A=\int |f|$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

We work on some domain $\Omega$ which may or may not be bounded.

If $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., if $\int |f| < \infty$, and if we know that $\int |f_n| \to A$ to some number $A$, is $$A=\int |f|?$$

I don't think this falls under DCT and I have been unable to show a counterexample.

Comment: Try the function $f_n$ which is the characteristic function of the interval $[n,n+1]$. Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ everywhere, $\int 0 = 0$, yet $\int f_n=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: In other words, observe that the inequality in Fatou's Lemma can be strict.